# Sorting of values in hashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I need ot sort the HashMap with values like below
4,2021-05-29
1,2021-06-01
2,2021-07-01
3,2021-08-01
with   1,2021-05-29 2,2021-06-01 3,2021-07-01 4,2021-08-01
I tried the below code but that doesnt work

```
`List<Map.Entry<Long, Date> > list =  new LinkedList<Map.Entry<Long, Date> > 
(creditRecMap.entrySet());
    creditRecMap.entrySet();
        // Sort the list
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<Long, Date> >() {
            public int compare(Map.Entry<Long, Date> o1,
                               Map.Entry<Long, Date> o2)
            {
                return (o2.getValue()).compareTo(o1.getValue());
            }
        });
         
        // put data from sorted list to hashmap
        HashMap<Long, Date> temp = new LinkedHashMap<Long, Date>();
        for (Map.Entry<Long, Date> aa : list) {
            temp.put(aa.getKey(), aa.getValue());
        }
```

Comment: in your data the `key` changes based on the ordering of the values, is that intentional and what doesn't work?

Comment: Maps can't generally be sorted by value, and `HashMap` can't be sorted at all. Your attempt _might_ work, but you're trying to sort what appears to be the underlying `HashMap` without making copies. (Note also that `Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue)` would be much more readable.)

Comment: that is intentional @ThomasJungblut

Comment: What do you mean by sort? Do you mean keys with lowest values occur first? And if the keys have the same value, how would you sort them? Would you check the value the key maps to?

Comment: @DarkEagle

Yes i need the lowest date first with key 1 and then second date and then third

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a sorted stream of Map entries by value.
`creditRecMap.entrySet().stream.sorted((entry1, entry2) -> entry1.getValue().getTime() - entry2.getValue().getTime());`